# My caeser cipher prints encrypted text 5 times

Tags: python

The problem is that when I run my code, it gives me 5 encrypted texts, but I only want it once. It prints the same encrypted text five times in five different lines. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
import string
encryptedtext = ""
currentpos = 0

plainText = input("Please enter your message: ")
offset = int(input('enter offset (Negative number to decrypt)'))
plainTextLen = len(plainText)

for x in plainText:
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    plainText = plainText.lower()
    position = alpha.find(plainText[0])
    position += 5
    encryptedText= ""
    encryptedText += alpha[position]
    encrypted_alpha = (alpha[alpha.index(alpha[offset]):len(alpha)])+ alpha[0:offset]
    data = str.maketrans(alpha,encrypted_alpha)
    final_message = str.translate(plainText, data)
    print(final_message)
print("",encryptedText,"")
```

Comment: You're looping through `plainText` and doing exactly the same thing each time. Take out the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for x in plainText:
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    plainText = plainText.lower()
    position = alpha.find(plainText[0])
    position += 5
    encryptedText= ""
    encryptedText += alpha[position]
    encrypted_alpha = (alpha[alpha.index(alpha[offset]):len(alpha)])+ alpha[0:offset]
    data = str.maketrans(alpha,encrypted_alpha)
    final_message = str.translate(plainText, data)
    print(final_message)
```

is looping through the contents of `plainText` using a variable `x`. But you don't use `x`, so you're just doing the exact same thing (including printing) N times.
Take out the loop and just run the code once.

```
# for x in plainText: <- removed
alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
plainText = plainText.lower()
position = alpha.find(plainText[0])
position += 5
encryptedText= ""
encryptedText += alpha[position]
encrypted_alpha = (alpha[alpha.index(alpha[offset]):len(alpha)])+ alpha[0:offset]
data = str.maketrans(alpha,encrypted_alpha)
final_message = str.translate(plainText, data)
print(final_message)
```